# Does anybody know PhpStorm plugin for cut off CSS selectors?

Tags: phpstorm

I am looking Phostorm plugin or third party tool for cut off CSS selectors. For example:

Source code:

html body div custom class.h1 { color: red }

Fixed code after plugin applied:

class.h1 { color: red }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution. Try to use set compatibility mode to Vista for PhpStorm icon. It is working for me.